# PHP file upload error conditions

Tags: php, file-upload, content-management-system

I am trying to create a profile editing setup. It seems as though the information is edited only when an image is being uploaded. I found out that allowing the error message to be a condition allows for some more manipulation so I attempted it now my condition statement is not working as it should.

```
if($_FILES['files']['error']==0) {

    print_r($_FILES['files']['error']);
    echo "if";

    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $file => $name) {
        $filename = $name;

        try{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$file],'uploads/'.$filename)) {
                $updateInfo = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET image       = :image, aboutme     = :aboutme WHERE id = :id");

                $updateInfo->bindParam(":image", $filename);
                $updateInfo->bindParam(":id", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
                $updateInfo->bindParam(':aboutme', $aboutme);

                $updateInfo->execute(); 
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        } 
    }
} elseif($_FILES['files']['error'] == 4) {
    print_r($_FILES['files']['error']);
    echo "Elseif";

    try{
        $updateInfo = $db->prepare("
        UPDATE users
        SET 
            aboutme     = :aboutme

            WHERE id = :id
        ");
        $updateInfo->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
        $updateInfo->bindParam(':aboutme', $aboutme);


        $updateInfo->execute();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    } 
} else{
    print_r($_FILES['files']['error']);
    echo "else";
}
```

}

When I check what array is being sent, its the correct one but the wrong condition, ie: it would run the else statement no matter the file check.

My question:

Is there something wrong with my code, with the exception of any security or efficiency flaws?

Comment: print_r($_FILES['files']) and check what are you getting.

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Thank you for your comment. If I try uploading an image i get the following:   

`Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => image_uploaded_from_ios_720.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phps23tdT ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 19635 ) ) else`

And without trying to upload an image:  
 
`Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) else`

Comment: see error is array: [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) so you have to check like: $_FILES['files']['error'][0]

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Wow. Thank you so much. Is there a way to not have to include the [0]? I thought it was only needed if you have multiple files being uploaded.. :/

Comment: see here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Alright, Thank you. If you don't mind. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: sure and happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES['files']['error'] returns error code along with the file array. There are different type of error codes, all codes are mentioned in following link with details:

Please check by

> print_r($_FILES['files'])

and see what are you getting in response.

As you posted your array response, you can get error code by  $_FILES['files']['error'][0] or use switch case as mentioned in following link.

See here for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Also regarding debugging, always debug code step by step from top to bottom. Check $_POST, $_FILES, $_SERVER etc details if you get some problem particular related to data process.