# codeigniter upload files checking if empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to check if file upload is empty or not, but it just goes one way.. Always empty. here's what I have.

```
if(isset($_FILES) && @$_FILES['file_upload']['error'] != '4'){
    //Upload file then insert ticket info to database
}else{
    //Just insert info to database
}
```

it always goes to the if statement whether the file field is empty or not.

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417033/php-file-upload-error-conditions/43417958#43417958

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it

Comment: I am guessing your input type file attribute name is mismatch.

Comment: @teshvenk Here's my input type name <input type="file" name="file_upload[]" multiple />

Comment: @TheTruth Since it is multiple file upload you have have to use like

$_FILES['file_upload']['error'][0]

Comment: Show your file upload input and form tags

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
if ($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] !== 4){
  //Upload file then insert ticket info to database
} else {
    //Just insert info to database
}
```

Simple method is (recommend):

```
if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) { 
   //Upload file then insert ticket info to database
} else {
    //Just insert info to database
}
```

Comment: No, it's not :( sadly

Comment: Try: `var_dump(empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])` and post an error was receive in your question.

Comment: it doesn't return anything